# How to execute certain command after new kernel is installed

Tags: linux-kernel, automation, virtualbox, upgrade

Every time a new kernel is downloaded and installed by unattended upgrades Virtual Box service gets broken.

So, when I try to start a VM box after reboot I get the error:

```
VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

To fix it I issue `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority low virtualbox-dkms`

How can I automate that?

Comment: This happens automatically for me. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the Oracle repositories for VirtualBox. Sorry I know that's not a solution, I'm just saying that it should work, though I don't know what's wrong in your case

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Have no idea what might go wrong